# Unable to synchronize Windows time with local NTP server

Tags: windows-10, ntp

I have installed `NTP` server on a machine in `LAN` (pfSense), unfortunately, Windows can't synhronize time with it

[image]

Why and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

`sc stop w32time`

`w32tm /unregister`

`w32tm /register`

`sc start w32time`

`w32tm /config /update /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:192.168.10.1`

`w32tm /resync /rediscover /nowait`

That's my suggested method. The guy in the comments is 100% correct, you should not advertise as a reliable source.  As for citing references, this isn't rocket science. I got that straight off the top of my head.

Comment: To verify you are sync'd up with 10.1 run "w32tm /query /source "

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your time server is not trust by Windows 10. Try the following command in a CMD prompt with elevated privileges:

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:192.168.10.1
w32tm /config /reliable:yes
net start w32time
w32tm /resync /rediscover
```

You can check your configuration with:

```
w32tm /query /configuration
```

[Sources](https://blog.zwindler.fr/2015/09/05/debug-client-ntp-linux-vers-ntp-windows-server/)

Comment: `w32tm /config /reliable:yes` configures the local machine to advertise itself on the network as an authoritative (reliable) time source. This should not be set on workstation computers.

Comment: @olivierb2, we always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but can you please site the source for your answer?

Comment: Apologies for the miss, I just edited by post.